# How to build Atlaskit editor using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm relatively new in React and I have problem with building simple Atlaskit editor. I'm trying to do this using Vite, here are the details:

```
// package.json
{
"name": "atlaskit-editor",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@atlaskit/editor-core": "^185.8.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
}
}
```

Here App.tsx

```
// App.txs
import { Editor } from "@atlaskit/editor-core";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Editor />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Main.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Index.tsx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is blank page with the following error in the console:
[image]

Here is a simple example, could someone help to reproduce it?
https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/editor/editor-core/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

You declare the process object as an empty project to avoid the issue

if you are using vite this may work for you

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

const processEnv = {};

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "process.env": processEnv,
  },
  // ...the rest of your config
});
```